# Write a Dog constructor that has one argument, the name, and calls the super constructor passing it the name and the animal type “dog”. cant pass type

Tags: java

```
public class Pet
{
    private String name;
    private String type;

    public Pet(String n, String t)
    {
        name = n;
        type = t;
    }
    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void speak()
    {
        System.out.println("grr!");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Pet p = new Pet("Sammy","hamster");
        System.out.println(p.getType());
        p.speak();

        Dog d = new Dog("Fido");
        System.out.println(d.getType());
        d.speak();
        //Cat c = new Cat("Fluffy");
        //System.out.println(c.getType());
        //c.speak();
    }
}
class Dog extends Pet
{
    public Dog(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public void speak(){
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }
}
// Add a Cat class
```

How do I add "type" to this without adding another String to my parameter?
I've tried other ways that obviously didn't work but I still tried anyway. So how do I add another object to my super class from Pet without adding more to my parameter?

Comment: The constructor of Pet takes two arguments, the first argument is the name, the second argument is the type. What is the type for a Dog?

Comment: What do you mean "can't pass type"?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor with one parameter for the dog class:

```
 public Dog(String name) {
    super(name, "dog");
 }
```